# Running multiple Phusion passenger instances for one rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, cluster-computing, phusion

is it possible (or a good idea) to run multiple Phusion passenger instances on 1 server (same rails app on many instances).

I wanna use Nginx as Frontend webserver (loadbalancer).

Any best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible and quite easy. Just you need to run it on different port.

You can refer [this link](http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/).
In this, they have ran same application on multiple ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and works fine. Just make sure they're assigned on different ports.